# SQL Adding a Column to table, based on a inner join

Tags: sql, inner-join

I have two firebird tables, T1 & T2.

```
T1 columns: pid, ean, desc

A T1 record: 1234, '102030', 'the desc'
```

and

```
T2 columns: eid, many_eans, eandesc 

A T2 record: 4321, '634232;**102030**;273728', 'the ean desc'
```

I can with this select query get my results:

```
select  T1.pid
      , T1.ean
      , T1.desc
      , T2.eandesc

  from table1 as T1
inner
  join table2 as T2 
    on T1.ean like '%' || T2.many_eans || '%'
```

But the query takes too long, therefore I want to add a Column to T1 something like compute by, that adds the T2.eandesc text to the T1 table where T1.ean like %T2.many_eans%

After adding the column I would just do this query to get my data.

```
select pid, ean, desc, eandesc from T1
```

How do I add the T2.eandesc to T1 ?

Comment: Wow!  What a great reason not to use a lousy data format.  If you try to stuff a bunch of integer ids into a string, then you are going to suffer.  The right way to store a list in SQL is to use a table, not a string.

Comment: Would the right way be by creating a view?

Comment: Gordon. Agreed. But I have no control of the received data. So I have to handle them as this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently your `T2` table is not normalized and you are storing CSV data in the `many_eans` column.  I would advise you to restructure `T2` such that one `ean` appears per record, e.g.

```
T2 columns: eid, ean, eandesc 

4321, '634232', 'the ean desc'
4321, '102030', 'the ean desc'
4321, '273728', 'the ean desc'
```

Then, the following simple join would suffice to get your result:

```
select
    T1.pid
    T1.ean
    T1.desc
    T2.eandesc
from table1 as T1
inner join table2 as T2 
    on T1.ean = T2.ean
```

Note that if a given `ean` could appear more than once in one of your current strings, then can use `select distinct` instead to ensure that you don't get duplicate results from `T1` in your result set.

Comment: I agree, that the way the many_eans is stored is not ideal. It is possible to do a query that extract and create the data as you describe?

Comment: @ITNET Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056507/how-to-split-comma-separated-string-inside-stored-procedure) for some suggestions on how to explode a CSV string to separate records in another table in Firebird SQL.