# Firebird SQL using "SIMILAR TO" instead of "IN" in "WHERE" clause

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

The following query gave me this error:

> -901 Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code = -901 Implementation limit exceeded Too many values (more than 1500) in member list to match
> against

```sql
SELECT 
 A, B, C
FROM 
  SampleTable 
WHERE A in ( 15806,15809,22069,22135.....)
```

I inserted more than 1500 values on this in clause, hence, the error. I found a solution by replacing "in" to "similar to" as the following:

```sql
SELECT 
 A, B, C
FROM 
  SampleTable 
WHERE A similar to ('15806|15809|22069|22135.....')
```

It seems to work, I can inject more than 1500 values. But this doesn't feel right, can someone confirm this is a viable solution to the error above? The ids are in a string list, so nothing I can do to change those values. I looked at the `similar to` documentation of Firebird and it doesn't mention anything about inserting it in where clause with ids as the way I'm doing it.

Comment: Let me rephrase my previous comment: what exactly is your concern or problem with the solution? It works, so it is a viable solution, so the answer to your question is "yes", which isn't very helpful and I think it doesn't address your actual concern which you haven't laid out. Personally, I would question why you even have a list of 1500+ of IDs to compare against, and wonder if there could be a better solution.

Comment: no, i  was just curiuos for future errors, in case an id is null for instance..or other areas i am not familiar with similar to option. Indeed you are right, a better query is the way to avoid injection of many ids, thanks Mark.

Comment: What `similar to` does is a regular expression match against the left-hand value. It will convert the value of `A` to a string if it isn't a string value. As with most SQL expressions, a comparison against null will result in null.

Comment: The next problem you'll encounter is the string literal limit. Consider using of a temporary table and join.

Comment: You perhaps could swap `A` and the string - see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13121470/976391 and for a more complex example - `Route 2` at https://stackoverflow.com/a/43997801/976391

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter sql based on C# List instead of a filter table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43997516/filter-sql-based-on-c-sharp-list-instead-of-a-filter-table)

Answer (score 0):

The clause **in** is limited to 1500 items. You can use join to join multiple selects.